# Cannot get websocket connection working with ec2 + application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, elastic-load-balancer

I am having trouble establishing a websocket connection. I have an aws ec2 instance that is running an SSL websocket server on a subdomain: api.example.com, on port 9999. My client application is running at www.example.com, the client sets up a listener:

```
new WebSocket('wss://api.example.com:9999');
```

This results in the browser giving me:

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

So my next idea was since my application load balancer already has an https listener setup on port 443 going to my api server, I changed my websocket listener setup to:

```
new WebSocket('wss://api.example.com/socket');
```

Then I made my nodejs (restify) webserver on the ec2 instance catch /socket with plans to redirect it to localhost:9999...  However, I put a console.log in that /socket endpoint prior to redirecting, and there is ***no logging happening***-- I also tried `wss://api.example.com:443/socket`, neither seems to hit the endpoint in my webserver.

Yet if I use curl, it works fine:

```
~>curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Host: api.example.com" -H "Origin: https://www.example.com" https://api.example.com/socket
HTTP/2 301
date: Tue, 26 Jun 2018 02:27:07 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 4
location: https://localhost:9999/localhost
server: restify
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.example.com
vary: origin
access-control-expose-headers: api-version, content-length, content-md5, content-type, date, request-id, response-time
```

although `https://localhost:9999/localhost` seems a little weird-- but regardless, when I use curl, it hits the endpoint and I see the log.

Comment: did you enable  sticky session in ur loadbalancer setting?

Comment: show rule of your load balancer, and no need to configure ssl at instance level when there is option at loadbalancer. which loadbalancer u are using?

Comment: I am using the "Application load balancer."  I do not see any "sticky session" option, where is this?  And I do need ssl at instance level because my socket sever requires a cert/private key.  I have two listeners on the load balancer, http 80, and https 443 (with an aws ssl cert), 80 and 443 both have their own groups that have targets of the ec2 instance.

Comment: I just found the stickiness checkbox for my port 443 target group.  What is that doing exactly, and how does it help websockets?  Also how long of a time period should I choose for websockets?

Comment: Also, I tried making a https port 9999 target group forwarding to the instance.. and hooked a https listener + ssl cert to that group--  enabled stickiness.  When I try new WebSocket('wss://api.example.com:9999') I get "failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503"  If I try making the target group TCP 9999 (I read somewhere in the docs that websockets on aws load balancers have to be TCP not HTTP), then I can't seem to attach a http or https listener to it....

Comment: 503 code mean ur service not communicating properly with the load balancer.check the health of your ec2 instance is it reachable to load balancer. what I will recommend first try with HTTP then try with https. sticky session is used for websocket support in ALB this help to keep session with same instance read doc.

Comment: after hours of painful troubleshooting, I finally figured out what is going on-- and asked a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053863/websocket-server-host-has-to-be-blank-in-order-to-work-on-ec2-instance-with-appl