# websocket server host has to be blank in order to work on ec2 instance with application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, amazon-elb

I have an aws application load balancer with an https listener on port 9999, forwarding to a group on port 9999 with an ec2-instance being the target.

If I run my websocket server with the host name configured to my domain `api.example.com`, then when the client tries to open a websocket connection it gets:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

However, if I configure my websocket server with an empty string instead of the domain, then it connects **just fine**!

This is problematic because the server I am intending to run on this instance automatically launches a websocket server **ONLY IF** there is a websocket host name configuration provided, so a blank string means the websocket server will never launch!  I would prefer to not have to hack the library to get around that condition.  So I am wondering, why in the world a blank string works, but the domain name does not?

I tried localhost, the ip of the box, etc, everything results in a 502 except a blank string!